# How to set a setTimeout after the drop event?

Tags: javascript

how can I set a timeout after drop event?
I want function(e) to run after a second.

here s the code

```
window.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
   document.getElementById('x-value').textContent = e.x;
   document.getElementById('y-value').textContent = e.y;
   alert(document.getElementById(event.target.id).id );

 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
   setTimeout(()=>{
       document.getElementById('x-value').textContent = e.x;
       document.getElementById('y-value').textContent = e.y;
       alert(document.getElementById(event.target.id).id );
   }, 1000);
 });
```